# Mycin like diagnosis system using gpt3 model

Tags: interactive, expert-system, gpt-3

I  wondering if we can build a Mycin like expert system using most advanced deep learning model like GPT3 by fine tuning medical domain knowledge. We build 40 years ago Mycin using symbolic approach but I am not sure it is possible now.